# change background colour using arrow keys

Tags: jquery

Im trying to change background colour on a arrow keys press. 
Im using an array to store the colors. it seems that i have several mistakes, but can't find them.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var array = ["#3D567C", "#013C8A", "#67A0D7", "FBFCFC", "#D9DFE1"]
    var counter = 0;
    var forward = 0;
    var backward = 0;
    var nextColor;
    var previousColor;

    forward = (counter + 1) % array.length;
    backward = (counter - 1)% array.length;

    nextColor = array[forward];
    previousColor = array[backward];

    switch(event.which) 
    {
         case 37: // arrow left
              $(".box").css("background-color", previousColor)
              console.log("ewjf")
              break;
        case 39: // arrow right
             $(".box").css("background-color", nextColor)
             break;
       default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said there are several issues.

Please check the code below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var array = ["#3D567C", "#013C8A", "#67A0D7", "FBFCFC", "#D9DFE1"]
    var counter = 0;


    $(document).keyup(function (event)
                      {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
  switch(event.which) {
        case 37: // arrow left
          counter--;
          if(counter ==-1)
          {
              counter=array.length-1;
          }
        $(".box").css("background-color", array[counter])

        break;

        case 39: // arrow right
           counter++;
          if(counter == array.length)
          {
              counter=0;
          }
        $(".box").css("background-color", array[counter])

        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
                      });

});
```

removed unwanted variables.
added keyup event to change color.

i have also added loop to change color continuously.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zwahxf4d/)

Answer (score 0):

if counter is said to 0 backward will have -1%5 = -1 array [-1] will result in undefined

```
forward = (counter + 1) % array.length;
backward = (counter - 1)% array.length;
```

in $(document).ready(fn) you can't process the keydown processing.

You need to define keydown event

```
$(document).bind("keydown",function(){
// here you need to check the key and set back color.
})
```